# How to find the path of the current object in a for-eachobject loop

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find the path of the object currently being operated on in a `for-eachobject` loop. Can someone explain how to do this? I am trying to set the path of the source for `Copy-Item` to whatever path the file is on. This is the first project I have worked with Powershell on. Assume $Src has been properly instantiated.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Src -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {$_.Name -notmatch "Archive" -and ($_.PSIsContainer)}| 
ForEach-Object {
    $DateStr = $_.BaseName.Substring(0,2)+'/'+$_.BaseName.Substring(3,2)+'/'+$_.BaseName.Substring(6,4)  
    $FileDate = get-date $DateStr
    If ( $FileDate -ge $Date -and !($_.PSIsContainer)) {
        $ParentOjbect = $_.Directory 
        $Parent = $ParentOjbect.Name
        Copy-Item -Path (Join-Path -Path $Src -ChildPath '\*.txt' ) #this 
  #needs to be corrected to only point to the current file
-Dest (Join-Path $Dst ("$($_.Directory.Name) $($_.Name)")) -WhatIf
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 Copy-Item -Path (Join-Path -Path $_.FullName -ChildPath '\*.txt' )
```

I suggest you also use -WhatIf on that also to check it does what you expect first.

Comment: Thank you, it is now doing exactly what I want the code to do, according to the What-If, but nothing pops up in the folder like it is supposed to. Any idea why that is?

Comment: Have you removed the -whatif?

Answer (score 1):

`$_`, or `$PSItem` (PowerShell 3.0+), accesses the current object in the pipeline.  From here, you can access its members.

Comment: Thank you, it is now doing exactly what I want the code to do, according to the What-If, but nothing pops up in the folder like it is supposed to. Any idea why that is?